# C# - Simpler/Shorter way to make an 'if-or' statement

Tags: if-statement, shortcut

Is there any way to shorten this statement:

```
if(string.Equals("Hello") || string.Equals("Hi") || string.Equals("Hey")) { }
```

To something like:

```
if(string.Equals("Hello" || "Hi" || "Hey")) { }
```

It's not necessary, but can be handy.

Comment: This isn't c#, but I've used the following in other projects: `["Hello", "Hi", "Hey"].contains(string)`

Comment: Thank you, that is such a simple and great way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @thelaws who suggested using an array of the possible values and flipping the statement, which I got to work with:

```
if(new string[]{"Hello", "Hi", "Hey"}.Contains(value)) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((new List<string> { "Hello", "Hi", "Hey" }).Contains(yourValue))
{
//your code here 
}
```

Here I created a list of strings with values `Hello`, `Hi` and `Hey`. Then I am just searching whether the value of variable `yourValue` is present in the created list.

Comment: Can you expand a little on exactly what this does and how it might answer the OP?

Comment: I have just created a list of string with values Hello , Hi and Hey . Then I am just searching whether the value of variable yourValue is present in the created list. So this is one liner equivalent to his question. Hope this will clarify your question.